# Anylogic Database Integration to power BI?

Tags: database, powerbi, simulation, anylogic

How can I integrate Anylogic Database to power BI platform so that Power BI can generate from the simulation a real time data (display dashboard) ? (PS : am beginner in simulation modeling with AnyLogic)

Comment: The simplest way is to have PowerBI pointed to a folder [like here](https://powerbi.tips/2016/06/loading-data-from-folder/) and then have AnyLogic produce a csv of the output after each run. If you need to stream data then it can be accomplished using Java or Python.